# rule for present perfect: the woman has ordered wine

Tags: present-perfect

> The woman has ordered wine.

In this sentence the woman has not yet received the wine?

Or did the woman order in the current context, and maybe already received the wine?

Comment: Without any further information or context, I can just say that the ordering process has been finished prior to the moment of speaking.

Comment: so, without anymore information, is it the same as saying: "the woman ordered wine" ?

Comment: We cannot know for certain, but present perfect marks events in the past that have an important effect on the present. In this case, ordering the wine in the past is most important in the present if the wine is not yet received. Otherwise, the wine being received is most important, and one might use, "The woman has received the wine that she ordered."